# Why Int64 and UInt64 are of same size

Tags: c#, .net

I'm asking in context of `C#`. Why both `Int64` and `UInt64` are of same size i.e. `64-bits`. Same goes to other Int variables also.

I was expecting `UInt` to be smaller in size at least a bit as it do not need to represent the `-` sign, am I expecting some illogical thing here?

Comment: Unsigned types can represent larger values. e.g. UInt8 goes from 0 to 255, Int8 from -128 to 127. Both support 2^8 = 256 different values. The sign is represented via [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: Yes. Unsigned and signed types of a certain size have the same ... size by definition. Signed types use one bit for the sign, as a result their maximum range is half that of the unsigned types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental reason is that modern CPUs are `64-bit` ones.
So it's far more easier to implement

```
  64-bit integer - one CPU register  (say RAX)
  32-bit integer - half CPU register (EAX)
  16-bit integer - 1/4 (AX)
   8-bit integer - 1/8 (AH)
```

otherwise (for say `96-bit`) you have to design your own support for, say, integer overflow detection etc. which will be slow.

Answer (score 12):

The `64` in `Int64` and `UInt64` means the size of the integer is 64 bits. That's why they are the same size.

The *size* is the same, but *range* is different (also due to the significant bit):

- UInt64: 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615;
- Int64: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Answer (score 3):

It all comes down to *what the most significant bit is used for*. In signed data it indicates the sign; in unsigned data it is *just another bit*. This means that unsigned data can represent values twice as large in magnitude, but only represent positive values (and zero) - for example, in the case of 64-bits, unsigned values are 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 - where-as signed values are -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 thru 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

It is easier to see for 8-bit: -128 to 127 versus 0 to 255. The number of possible values is identical.

Answer (score 1):

Here there is the [Integral Types Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx) for C#. If you look there you can see:

> long -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 Signed 64-bit integer
>
> ulong 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 Unsigned 64-bit integer

If you look, the "range" of both is the same, 2 ^ 64 (including the 0)

Probably easier with smaller data types:

> sbyte -128 to 127 Signed 8-bit integer
>
> byte 0 to 255 Unsigned 8-bit integer

Both have a "range" of 256 values, both of them are 8 bits, and 2^8 == 256

Note that signed and unsigned types have the same range of values because historically nearly all the processors use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for numbers. If they had used [ones' complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) then the effective range of signed numbers would be one less than the range of unsigned numbers, because there would be two 0 values (positive and negative 0)